# Change a path with sed and use the result in copy function?

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd, copy

I need to convert some .sh files to .cmd, because i'm under windows - but with Mingw64 and some linux utilities (like sed, grep, etc...).

I'm struggling on a little problem : i have some path in the .sh script which are Linux paths, so with `/`, like: 
`FILEPATH=/opt/My/Troublesome/Path`

Since i don't want to re-write all the paths, i've just copy/paste those in the .cmd like that: 
`set "FILEPATH=/opt/My/Troublesome/Path"`
Then i created an opt directory in C:, and windows is able to find those path. I can do `cd %FILEPATH%` without a prob.

However, `copy` is not that good. when i try `copy %FILEPATH%/Myfile .`it complains about syntax. When i do the same with double-quote, it says file not found.

I've tried using sed to change the path and copy it in a same line, but i can't manage to make it work. i've done:

`echo "/opt/My/Troublesome/Path/Myfile ." | sed "s~\/~\\~g"`

and it gives me that: `\opt\MyTroublesome\Path\Myfile .`

Since it's exactly what i want, i've tried to pipe it to copy, but it's not working (i've never been good with pipe, anyway):

`echo "/opt/My/Troublesome/Path/Myfile ." | sed "s~\/~\\~g" | copy`

It says wrong syntax. I've tried a lot more things, like that: 
`copy < echo "/opt/My/Troublesome/Path/Myfile ." | sed "s~\/~\\~g"`
but still not working.

Moreover, those are the things i've tried in my Mingw shell, not sure what will change in the script using the %FILEPATH% variable.

Any idea? Is it even possible to do that in one line?

PS: since i got `sed`, i'm pretty sure i can get `cp` too. But i would like to have as little linux function as possible in my .cmd. `sed` will be used in it later, so it's ok to have it, because windows has no equivalent, but since `copy` exists on windows there is no reason to use `cp`

Comment: You cannot just pipe paths to the `copy` command, you need to provide them as arguments; you could store the paths in variables, like `set "FILEPATH=/opt/My/Troublesome/Path"`), and use a [modified value](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) then, like `copy "C:%FILEPATH:/=\%\MyFile" .`...

Comment: This is actually working, thank you! You can give it as an answer. I've read about modified values before, but i didn't think i could use the like that (in my mind they could just change a part of the string, not every occurence of this part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`copy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) expects paths to be provided as command line arguments, so you cannot pass them over using a [pipe (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

You could store the Unix-/Linux-style path in a variable, then use [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to replace every `/` by `\` and immediately use the result by the `copy` command:

```cmd
rem // Store Unix-(Linux-)style path in variable:
set "FILEPATH=/opt/My/Troublesome/Path"
rem // Precede drive and replace `/` by `\`:
copy "C:%FILEPATH:/=\%\MyFile" .
```